# Can I end a database transaction after starting an activity?

Tags: java, android

I'm just looking for best practices in this scenario.

During the competition step of my activity I establish a database transaction and I want for now that if a failure happens that the activity does not transition to the next activity and also that the transaction is rolled back.

Thus, is it okay that I formulate my code with the end transaction call AFTER the start activity call as shown in the following code?

```java
try {
    DatabaseAccess.mDatabase.beginTransaction();
    Task tt = new Task(lngTaskID);
    Time tm = new Time(tt.mlngTimeID);
    if(tm.mlngRepetition <= 0) {
        tt.deleteTask();
    } else {
        TaskInstance ti = new TaskInstance(lngInstanceID);
        ti.finishInstance(3);
    }
    DatabaseAccess.mDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Viewer_Tasklist.class);
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
DatabaseAccess.mDatabase.endTransaction();
```

Comment: I don't know your database API, but the typical thing you would do in case of an error in the middle of the transaction would be to _rollback_ the transaction, to leave you with the state before the transaction even started.

Comment: The database is sqlite which requires either setting the transaction as successful or defaulting to auto rolling back on ending of transaction if not. So in this case I believe that portion is right. Mostly I'm concerned about any issues related to the endTransaction being after the startActivity() call.